# Extending a Java Swing class in Clojure

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, clojure

I'm trying to extend a Java Swing component in Clojure, i.e. I want to extend a javax.swing.JComponent and add some custom methods implemented in pure Clojure in addition to all the standard inherited methods.

I've tried using "proxy" which works great if I just want a single instance (in the same way as an anonymous inner class). However I'd really like a named class so that I can generate an arbitrary number of instances.

What's the recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [gen-class](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/gen-class) (note that you can use it as an in-line function or in the namespace declaration).

```
(gen-class :extends javax.swing.JComponent ...)
```

Comment: thanks Greg - however does this mean I will be forced to use AOT compilation? I'd quite like to be able to run this all at the REPL if possible.....

Comment: Yes, you'd have to use AOT compilation with this approach. If you need this purely in-REPL, perhaps you could just wrap the call to proxy in a function which returns the proxy object?

Comment: Thanks Greg - the proxy method works very nicely. I was worried that successive calls would end up generating completely new anonymous class definitions but it appears that the compiler is clever enough to create a single class instance